# add execute attribute to a file in elisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I know function set-file-modes but it does not support things like "u+x".

Is there a function(s) which supports things like "u+x" in elisp?

**Update complete solution:**

```
(set-file-modes fname (file-modes-symbolic-to-number "u+x" (file-modes fname)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at `file-modes-symbolic-to-number` to convert "u+x" to a number.